# What causes these error messages when trying to open LibreOffice Writer?

Tags: 12.10, libreoffice

After reinstalling Ubuntu 12.10 (due to a boot problem), each time I open **LibreOffice Writer [Version 3.6.2.2 (Build ID: 360m1(Build:2))]**, two error messages pop up, both stating `error loading BASIC of document`

The first:

> file:///home/ariel/.config/libreoffice/3/user/basic/Standard/script.xlb/:General error. General input/output error.

The second:

> file:///home/ariel/.config/libreoffice/3/user/basic/Standard/dialog.xlb/:General error. General input/output error.

What is the cause of these messages and how can I correct them?

Comment: I'm providing some links. See if they help. If they do, you can post an answer to your own question: http://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=56961 ; http://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=16588 ; http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/1641/error-loading-basic-of-document-file/ . OTOH, Onickyet's answer seems relevant.

Comment: Same error for me, but a few years later and redhat centos 3.10, libreoffice 5 64bit. If remove or change the .xlb/.xlc files then open office runs, mouse works . . but keyboard doesn't work. . . . !??

Answer (score 1):

LibreOffice is looking for these two files and can't find them. All you need to do is create the files. It's ok for the files to be empty.

The easiest way to do this is to issue commands in the terminal.

Close LibreOffice.

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> to open a terminal. In the terminal you can copy and past the following commands. To paste in the terminal, use a right click and choose Paste from the popup menu, or click the scroll wheel on your mouse. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after each command. Enter commands one at a time.

```
cd ~/.config/libreoffice/3/user/basic/Standard
```

Check to see if the files are already there.

```
ls
```

If the files are there, something else is causing the problem. If they are not there, you just need to create them.

```
touch script.xlb
```

and after <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
touch dialog.xlb
```

Restart Libreoffice.

Comment: Sorry. I'm a very basic user and don't know how to go that directory and how to create the new files. Will you kindly explain step by step?

Comment: I read the links but yet I don't know how to do.

Comment: Open a Terminal (for instance by pressing Control+Meta+T). Then type 'cd .config/libreoffice/3/user/basic/Standard'. With 'ls' you get the content of the directory listed. Then proceed with the steps mentioned above.

Comment: When I pasted the first command to the terminal and pressed enter I got: ariel@ariel-MS-7592:~/.config/libreoffice/3/user/basic/Standard$  . Nothing else happened. I tried to create the two folders and restart Libreoffice but the same error messages are still there.

Comment: The files "script.xlb" and "dialog.xlb" are where they were  supposed to be, so the problem seems to derive from something else.